# How do i mock a function being called inside the run method of a python threading.Thread inherenting class from the main thread

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-multithreading

> 

i have a function in a my_fuction.py

```
def my_function():
    # do something
    print("doing something")
    return True
```

i also have a a threading.Thread inhereting class called my_thread.py

```
from my_function import my_function
from threading import Thread, Event
import time


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="MyThread")
        self.running = Event()

    def run(self):
        self.running.set()

        while self.running.is_set():
            return_value = my_function()
            print(return_value)
            time.sleep(3)
```

I want to test MyThread run method mocking my_function  such that the run will not call the real my_function function but the mocked one

i have a unittest script for testing MyThread  called test_my_thread.py and is as follows:

```
from my_thread import MyThread
import unittest
import time
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch


def mock_my_function():
    print("not doing something")
    return False


class TestMyThread(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_thread = MyThread()

    def test_my_thread_run_method(self):
        with patch("my_function.my_function", side_effect=mock_my_function) as mock_func:
            with patch.object(MyThread, "my_function", mock_my_function) as patched_my_function:
                self.my_thread.run()
                time.sleep(5)
                self.my_thread.running.clear()
                self.my_thread.join()
                patched_my_function.assert_called_once()  # this method will fail which i assume is because the function was not patched in the MyThread.run method  were it is used
```

How can I mock 'my_function' inside the run of MyThread or is there an alternative method of testing if it is running without actually running it (an alternative to mocking it) .

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example, although I did set up what I think is a similar situation, with most of your code. You need to patch the instance of my_function in my_thread. For me it was something like "somepath.my_thread.my_function". The path is a little different for me because your setup was missing some info. I'd be happy to post my full code, but I'd appreciate a reproducible setup in the question.

Comment: You don't want to patch the actual definition of my_thread. You want to patch the name my_function being used in my_thread, so patch('my_thread.my_function', ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding to you earlier. I really appreciate you helping out. I'm sorry for any inconvenience caused by the code. I have made some edits. However, when using the solution you provided, I encountered an AttributeError: "<class 'my_thread.MyThread'>" does not have the attribute 'my_function'.

Answer (score -1):

MyThread has already imported my_function.my_function, and it now has its own reference to that function, which is what MyThread will call. That is the reference you need to patch. It is "my_thread.my_function"

You're making the common mistake of trying to patch where the function was defined, but the patch merely replaces a name, not the actual function. What you need to patch is "my_thread.my_function"

The official documentation has a good explanation here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Here are some other unrelated changes:

You call run() on the thread, instead of start(), so the unit test waits and never gets to the sleep or join.

I also changed the sleep time because your test causes mock_func to be called twice, so assert_called_once() correctly fails with the message

> "Expected 'my_function' to have been called once. Called 2 times.\nCalls: [call(), call()]."

I needed to add a call to unittest.main() so I could start the test with "python test_my_thread.py" You probably started the test another way, so ignore that.

```
import unittest
import time
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_thread import MyThread

def mock_my_function():
    print("mock function called")
    return False

class TestMyThread(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_thread = MyThread()

    def test_my_thread_run_method(self):
        with patch("my_thread.my_function", side_effect=mock_my_function) as mock_func:
            self.my_thread.start()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.my_thread.running.clear()
            self.my_thread.join()
            mock_func.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: it worked perfectly and resolved the issue. I really appreciate you walking me through the solution. Thanks.